# Nickname command doesn't replace UserMention with nothing when changing nickname

Tags: java, discord

I recently found this bug: When a user has no nickname in the server and you try to rename them with my command it will name it like `S!nickname <@userMention> e` =  (the username) `<@userId> e`

Tried doing some things like renaming the user twice or replacing the mention twice but it doesn't work...

Here's my line that renames it (Should be the only one which is important):

```
event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0).modifyNickname(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().substring(11).replace(event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0).getAsMention(), "")).queue();
```

oh and also a screenshot:
https://gyazo.com/bdb15091497ecb7d4e3d545a4f2eb582

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Also note you can embed images in your post directly, there is no need to link to third-parties.

Comment: Add more detail please. Also this way of cascading function calls without any error handling is not safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String#split` to properly parse the command:

```java
String command = "s!nickname <@!id> new nickname";
String[] parts = command.split("\\s+", 3);
member.modifyNickname(parts[2]).queue();
```

Your problem is that you expect the mention string to always be the same. This is an incorrect assumption since there are 2 different formats for mentions that are used interchangeably. The `replace` function will not be able to properly replace the content if the mention format differs and will simply return the same string.

Your use of replace is questionable considering you know that the part you want to remove is **always** at the start of the string and followed by a space. This is very easy to parse using either `split` or `indexOf` with `substring`. I also recommend to start using variables to avoid 200 character long lines like this.